# Can I use bet with expect?

Tags: vocabulary

I bet you did not **expect** to receive an order from German. You were wrong.

Would it be better to use "hope"instead of "expect" in this case ?

Comment: bet and hope do not have the same meaning **at all**.

Comment: The words ***You were wrong*** can only be a separate sentence in the cited context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Do you think sentence (3) in my answer, incorporating "you were wrong" by using  "but", is valid?

Comment: @David Siegel: Learners often ask here whether some combination of elements represents "tautology". Most of the time I think that's a pointless question, because tautology is a natural feature of English anyway. But I must say that example #3 in your answer strikes me as slightly "odd", because informal ***I bet you didn't expect X*** is nearly always used to mean ***X happened**, against your expectations*. It seems a bit pointless to add ***You were wrong*** when that's effectively what you just said anyway! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentences:

> - (1) I bet you did not **expect** to receive an order from Germany.
> - (2) I bet you did not **hope** to receive an order from Germany.

are both grammatically valid and natural, but they have significantly different meanings. They are in no way interchangeable. Sentence (1) says that the speaker believes that the listener did not expect (anticipate) the order. Sentence (2) says that the speaker thinks that the listener either did not wish for the order, or did not have even an uncertain (weak) expectation of getting the order.

By the way "you were wrong" could be incorporat4ed into sentence (1) using a conjunction, such as:

> (3)  I bet you did not expect to receive an order from Germany, **but** you were wrong.

This wouldn't work as \well with sentence (2).

Comment: I do not believe, that for reasons of logic, one can include "you were wrong" as part of that sentence. Because it is not 100% certain that the order was "expected". Otherwise the speaker would have said "You expected..." rather than "I bet you expected...". That I suggest is what @FumbleFingers' comment is about.

Comment: @WS2 The speaker in my sentence (3) could have been engaging in understatement. In any case, grammatical usage often fails to follow what might seem to be the logical meaning of a situation.  I think my (3) is grammatically proper, nor did FF say otherwise, FF did not say anything about that variant. Nor is it the main issue of the question.

Comment: I think it needs an "if so", and I would change the "but" to "and". "I bet you did not expect *xyz*, and if so you were wrong".